# How to get table total pages count

Tags: postgresql

How to get table total pages (block) count ?

Would be this correct measurement:

```
SELECT pg_table_size('my_table'::regclass) / current_setting('block_size')::BIGINT;
```

?

Comment: can you please tell more about the context?

Comment: @Abdel - I mean, how to get total page quantity for certain table:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-page-layout.html

Answer (score 0):

To check number of pages do one of

```
SELECT relpages FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'my_table';
```

or

```
explain (analyse, buffers)
select * from my_table;
```

and check total numbers of buffers (hit+read)

For size in bytes- it depends if you include auxiliary relations (TOAST table, free space map, visibility map).

For more details see
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/325261/difference-between-total-table-size-and-size-of-all-pages-in-postgresql

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/measure-the-size-of-a-postgresql-table-row